# Tabular - columns wider than \textwidth

Tags: tables, columns, width, textwidth, column-width

I am trying to have table exactly between margins using \textwidth. Unfortunately, when I am using \textwidth my table is too large and I do not know why. (my code is for django template, but I was checking it in TexStudio also).

I am trying to have such tables (note that 18cm is my \textwidth, as I have a4paper and both left and right margins = 1,5cm)

```
    \begin{tabular}{|p{18cm}|}
    \hline
    aaa\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{|p{.08\textwidth}|p{.08\textwidth}|p{.08\textwidth}|p{.08\textwidth}|p{.16\textwidth}|p{.2\textwidth}|p{.2\textwidth}|p{.12\textwidth}|}
    
\hline
    PWM & O2 & CO  & CO2 & Temp. spalin & Ciśni. gaz przed EV & Ciśn gazu ze EV & Prąd jon. \\ \hline
    -   & \% & ppm & \%  & oC           & mbar                & mbar            & microA    \\ \hline
    &    &     &     &              &                     &                 &           \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

where all widths sum up to 1, but table is too wide (the same result was when I specified width in cm).
In preamble I am using for whole document, but it doesn't matter if it is commented out or not :

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
```

All of the preamble :

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[left=1.50cm, right=1.50cm, top=1.50cm, bottom=1.50cm, width=18cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection}
{0em}{}
% \usepackage{roboto}
% \usepackage[sfdefault, thin]{roboto}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\newcommand{\mySmallSkip}{\hspace*{10mm}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\usepackage{showframe} 
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% default is 0pt
\textheight=160mm
```

and my table is like :
[image]

Comment: When calculating the column widths you did not take into account the `\tabcolsep` and the width of the vertical lines. This is why your table is wider than the textwidth.

Comment: Do you need automatic linebreaks inside the columns? If not, wouldn't simple `l` type columns be sufficient? Your table would then be narrower than the textwidth.

Comment: `8pt` is not a valid option for the `article` document class.

Comment: @leandriis - thank you ! i want to have control over width of each column, so l is not an option - or I am wrong ?

Comment: @Mico thanks for pointing me that out

Comment: Other options include makecell and tabular* with \extracolsep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument of the `p` column type states the *usable* horizontal space, not the *total* horizontal space taken up by the column. Since the second `tabular` environment in your code contains 8 columns and 9 vertical-bar symbols, its total width is given by `1\textwidth+16\tabcolsep+9\arrayrulewidth`. With default values of `6pt` and `0.4pt` for `\tabcolsep` and `\arrayrulewidth`, respectively, the excess width over `\textwidth` is `99.6pt` -- roughly 1.4 inches, or ca 3.5cm. Yikes!

You wrote,

> I am trying to have table exactly between margins using `\textwidth`.

Then, by all means, use either a `tabularx` or a `tabular*` environment and set its width to `\textwidth`.

The first table in the following screenshot uses a `tabularx` column type and uses a centered version of the `X` column type for all 8 columns. It calculates the *relative* column widths as follows. First, notice that the 8 columns' widths must satisfy the ratio 2:2:2:2:4:5:5:3. Second, the *sum* of the relative column widths must be equal to 8, the number of columns of type X. Thus, 25x=8, or x=8/25=32/100. Thus, the relative column widths work out to 0.64 (4 times), 1.28, 1.6 (2 times), and 0.96.

While the first table uses `\hline` directives and lots of vertical bars (9, in fact!), the second table shows that a vast aesthetic improvement is easily achieved simply by getting rid of all vertical bars and using well-spaced alternatives to `\hline`.

Since automatic line-breaking doesn't actually seem to be needed, really, using `tabularx` is a form of overkill. The final table shows how to obtain nearly the same output with a `tabular*` environment, with 8 instances of LaTeX's basic `c` column type. Isn't `*{8}{c}` a lot easier than `*{4}{C{0.64}} C{1.28} *{2}{C{1.6}} C{0.96}`?

Whatever else you do, do employ a package such as `\mhchem` to typeset the names of chemical compounds and the `siunitx` package to typeset scientific units.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % A4: 21cm wide
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,mhchem,siunitx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X}

\begin{document}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % for the first two tables

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| *{4}{C{0.64}|} C{1.28}| *{2}{C{1.6}|} C{0.96} |}
\hline
PWM & \ce{O2} & \ce{CO} & \ce{CO2} & Temp.\ spalin & Ciśni.\ gaz przed EV & Ciśn gazu ze EV & Prąd jon. \\
\hline
-- & \% & ppm & \%  & \si{\celsius} & \si{\milli\bar} & \si{\milli\bar} & \si{\micro\ampere} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{1cm}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{4}{C{0.64}} C{1.28} *{2}{C{1.6}} C{0.96} @{}}
\toprule
PWM & \ce{O2} & \ce{CO} & \ce{CO2} & Temp.\ spalin & Ciśni.\ gaz przed EV & Ciśn gazu ze EV & Prąd jon. \\
\midrule
-- & \% & ppm & \%  & \si{\celsius} & \si{\milli\bar} & \si{\milli\bar} & \si{\micro\ampere} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{1cm}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{8}{c} }
\toprule
PWM & \ce{O2} & \ce{CO} & \ce{CO2} & Temp.\ spalin & Ciśni.\ gaz przed EV & Ciśn gazu ze EV & Prąd jon. \\
\midrule
-- & \% & ppm & \%  & \si{\celsius} & \si{\milli\bar} & \si{\milli\bar} & \si{\micro\ampere} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are two versions of your table. In both, I have used the `siunitx` package for the units as well as the `chemformula` package for the chemical formulae. In the first table, I have corrected the column width calculation to also take into account `\tabcolsep` and `\arrayrulewidth`. In the second table, I have used simple `l` type columns since the table in narrow enough to fit into the textwidth even without having to use `p` type columns:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % removed invalid 8pt option
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[margin=1.50cm]{geometry} % summarized left=1.50cm, right=1.50cm, top=1.50cm, bottom=1.50cm to margin=1.50cm
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{siunitx} % used for \si{...} command
\usepackage{chemformula} % added for \ch{...} command
\usepackage{calc}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{p{.08\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}
                p{.16\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|
                p{.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|
                p{.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|
                p{.12\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}
    
\hline
    PWM & \ch{O2}       & CO       & \ch{CO2} & Temp. spalin   & Ciśni. gaz przed EV  & Ciśn gazu ze EV      & Prąd jon.           \\ \hline
    -   & \si{\percent} & \si{ppm} & \%       & \si{\celsius}  & \si{mbar}            & \si{mbar}            & \si{\micro\ampere}  \\ \hline
        &               &          &          &                &                      &                      &                     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    
\hline
    PWM & \ch{O2}       & CO       & \ch{CO2} & Temp. spalin   & Ciśni. gaz przed EV  & Ciśn gazu ze EV      & Prąd jon.           \\ \hline
    -   & \si{\percent} & \si{ppm} & \%       & \si{\celsius}  & \si{mbar}            & \si{mbar}            & \si{\micro\ampere}  \\ \hline
        &               &          &          &                &                      &                      &                     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: many thanks !  I still do not have proper units etc as it is first draft of document and I am working on layout.